# Codename one GoogleConnect setScope is not effective

Tags: android, codenameone

I am using the new GoogleConnect thing and set the scope like

```
Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();    
gc.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");
...
gc.doLogin();
```

However, when the access token is generated and checked in 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=(accesstoken)
, it shows

```
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

Is it related to any recent updates or new build hint?
I am totally lost here. It is an Android build.
Thanks.

---

Edited to add gc.doLogin() code, to clarify that I am NOT trying to set the scope after the access token is generated.

Comment: Can you please file an issue on this? It's probably related to the migration, I'm not sure if the API will work in the exact same way though

Comment: Fine but sorry I don't know how to file an issue. Any helping page about this?

Comment: Found it and submitted issue #2172. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, setScope only works on the simulator

```
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
```

My scopes (for reference):

```
google.auth.scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me email profile
```